# Is there a way to simplify a map within a map?

Tags: clojure

I have data that is a sequence of sequences called re-val. The data is read in from a .csv file. Here is a sample of the data:

```
("      4999" "186300" "    194300" "         0" "380600" "325 " "57" 0)
("      1037" "184200" "    458800" "      6300" "649300" "111 " "124" 0)
```

Is there a simpler, cleaner way to apply trim to each member of each sequence than the following?

```
(def val1 (map (fn [x] (map #(cstr/trim %) x)) re-val))
```

The def is for repl diagnosis purposes. The actual s-o-s will be fed to a file write function.

Here is how the data looks from `(second val1)`.

```
("37" "184200" "458800" "6300" "649300" "111" "124" "0")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution could be improved a bit:

```
(def val1 (map #(map cstr/trim %) re-val))
```

To make it more readable I would probably resort to `for`:

```
(def val1 (for [line re-val] (map trim line)))
```

But that doesn't decrease number of characters...

Comment: OK, you're using a for loop to process each sequence of the sequence of sequences and then using map to trim each element of the sequence.

Comment: @octopusgrabbus Yeap, I usually prefer list comprehension to `map`, except for really simple cases. LC can be read from left to right and temporary var can have self-explaining name.

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
user> (def l '("        28" "186300" "    194300" "         0" "380600" "325 " "57" 0))
#'user/l
user>  (map trim (vec l))
("28" "186300" "194300" "0" "380600" "325" "57" "0")
```

Comment: I think that the question was what to do when list is 2d.

Answer (score 1):

```
=>((partial map (partial map clojure.string/trim)) data)

(("28" "186300" "194300" "0" "380600" "325" "57" "0")
 ("37" "184200" "458800" "6300" "649300" "111" "124" "0"))
```

If you have multiple nested collections, or a collection where the depth is unknown, and you want all strings trimmed, you could also use walks

```
=>(use 'clojure.walk)
  (postwalk #(if (string? %) (clojure.string/trim %) %) data)

[["28" "186300" "194300" "0" "380600" "325" "57" 0]
 ["37" "184200" "458800" "6300" "649300" "111" "124" 0]]
```